# Zend Framework 2: Set options as "selected" in select list

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm trying to set second product as selected in list, but code below doesn't work. Any idea. Thanks

```
$this->add(array(
        'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Select',
        'name' => 'manufacturer',
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Manufacturer name',
            'value_options' => $this->getManufacturer(),
            'empty_option'  => '--- select manufacturer ---',
        ),
        'attributes' => array(
            'value' => 2,
            'selected' => true,
        ),
    ));
```

Comment: There seems to be no issue with the code. Make sure the array populated through `$this->getManufacturer()`, at least has a key as `2`. Could also test with setting `'value_options' => array('1'=>'111','2'=>'222'),` and check if `222` is getting selected.

Comment: Are you getting this code from somewhere in the docs? `<select>` elements don't have a 'selected' attribute, normally you pre-select values via. the form, not the element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am giving a simple example here, hope it may help you.
As you mentioned for to get selected element, simple use the value attribute has the value of that selected element like:

```
    $this->add(array(
        'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Select',
        'name' => 'gender',
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Gender',
            'value_options' => array(
                '1' => 'Select your gender',
                '2' => 'Female',
                '3' => 'Male'
            ),
        ),
        'attributes' => array(
            'value' => '1' //set selected to '1'
        )
    ));
```

[you can prefer this link for more](http://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2012/10/01/zend-framework-2-extending-zendform-to-add-select-multicheckbox-emaildate-textarea-and-radio-element/)
And if you are getting

> haystack option is mandatory

then Add the disable_inarray_validator to the options:

```
    $this->add(array(
    ...
    'options' => array(
      'disable_inarray_validator' => true,
      'label' => 'county',
    ),
 ));
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken the value is part of the options not an attribute.

```
$this->add(array(
    'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Select',
    'name' => 'manufacturer',
    'options' => array(
        'label' => 'Manufacturer name',
        'value_options' => $this->getManufacturer(),
        'empty_option'  => '--- select manufacturer ---',
        'value' => '2'
    )
));
```

Comment: `value` is a part of the 'attributes' and not the 'options'.